# Trying to install Cocos2d templates on XCode 4.4 Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

I am attempting to install the cocos2d templates on XCode 4.4 on Mountain Lion.  I have both downloaded the lastest stable version from http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download and the latest code from https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone.

When I run ./install-templates.sh -f -u or just -f it installs templates into my ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates

[image: Like so]

However when I attempt to create a new project with a template I am only able to see the CNode  template under the cocos2d v2.x option.

[image: Like so]

There is nothing cocos2d related in the Other section.

I have attempted both moving the CNode class.xctemplate into the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x/ folder and also the opposite of moving all those .xctemplates into the ./File Templates/cocos2d v2.x/ folder, but I get the same result.

How can I correctly install the templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have clicked on "New -> File" rather than "New -> Project"

If you are using command-n that is new file, command-shift-n is new project.